# How can I get an "A" attribute that is related to ONLY ONE "B" attribute in a table? (SQL/LINQ)

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq

Suppose I have this table:

| Image | Perimeter |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| d | 3 |
| e | 1 |

I want to return the images that have relationship with only ONE perimeter.

The expected result would be images "a,d,e" because image "b" has relationship with perimeter "1" and "2".

The objective is to remove the releated image when I delete the perimeter. But if it is linked to another perimeter, I can't remove it.

How can I write this query with LINQ?

I think it would be something like this:

```
SELECT "ImageId" 
WHERE "PerimeterId" = PerimeterId IN 
(
SELECT "ImageId"
GROUP BY "ImageId"
HAVING COUNT("PerimeterId") = 1
)
```

but I don't know how to convert it to LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `NOT EXISTS`

```
var query = dbo.Table
    .Where(t => !dbo.Table.Any(t2 => t.Image = t.Image && t.Perimeter != t2.Perimeter));
```

Comment: It works! first i populated a list with all images relationed with the perimeterID:

return  _context.Db.Where(pt => pt.PerimeterId == perimeterId).Select(pt => pt.Image).ToList();

then i used this list to compare with anothers images attached to others perimeters:

return _context.Db.Where(pt=> pt.PerimeterId != perimeterId && imageIds.Contains(pt.ImageId)).ToList();

after, i just compared the two lists, and removed from the firts one the images of the second list

probabily there is a better way to do it, but it worked very well for me

Answer (score 0):

You can easily adapt this to only select the image part. But, if you are coming from SQL, thinking about "Selecting rows" based on a "HAVING()" group calculation, then you will want to look at the .SelectMany() LINQ method. This lets you "combine back together data partitioned into groups". While your needs are to only return "one from each group", it's easy to see where this can be adjusted.
This can be run in the "C# interactive window" of SSDT 2015:

```
struct imagePerimeter { //this might be whatever object type it is for you...
    public string Image { get; set; } //a,b,b,d,e
    public int Perimeter { get; set; } //1,1,2,3,1
}
Func<string, int, imagePerimeter> newIP = (i, p) => new imagePerimeter() { Image = i, Perimeter = p };
List<imagePerimeter> results = new List<imagePerimeter>() { {newIP("a",1) }
    ,{newIP("b",1) }
    ,{newIP("b",2) }
    ,{newIP("d",3) }
    ,{newIP("e",1) } };

Func<imagePerimeter, string> ipImage = (ip) => ip.Image; //the Func's "ipImage" and "newIP" could just be inlined into LINQ, but it helps to see and debug at times IMO. 
var imagesWithOnePerimeter = results.GroupBy<imagePerimeter, string>(ipImage) //even in SQL, the "GROUP BY" conceptually comes first, in LINQ, it comes first in code too!
    .Select(grp => new { Image = grp.Key, PerimeterCount = grp.Count(), Details = grp }) //there's probably a more technical term, but notice how we "carry forward" the original reference to [grp]
    .Where(subTotals => subTotals.PerimeterCount == 1)
    .SelectMany(filtered => filtered.Details.AsEnumerable())
    .ToList();
```